# Bidirectional OneToOne relationship in JPA-RS not traversable

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-rs

I use the simple entities below for exploring jpa-rs:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    private Address address;
}

@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String street;
    private String city;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private Employee employee;
}
```

Creating an `Employee` entity with an `Address` relation works like a charm:

```
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "address": {
    "street": "Street No. 1",
    "city": "A City"
  }
}
```

But i cannot travers the resulting objects by the `_link`s, like HATEOAS proposes.
The provided `students` example in the Eclipselink wiki (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples) allows this easily.
As far as i understand, i should be able to do the following:

1. fetch the employee with id 1: GET *url*/entity/Employee/1:

   ```
   {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "John Doe",
   "_relationships": [
   {
     "_link": {
       "href": "url/entity/Employee/1/address",
       "rel": "address"
     }
   }
   ],
   "address": {
   "_link": {
     "href": "url/entity/Address/2",
     "method": "GET",
     "rel": "self"
   }
   },
   "staff": []
   }
   ```
2. fetch the address of the employee: GET *url*/entity/Address/2:

   ```
   {
   "city": "A City",
   "id": 2,
   "street": "Street No. 1",
   "_relationships": [
   {
     "_link": {
       "href": "url/entity/Address/2/employee",
       "rel": "employee"
     }
   }
   ]
   }
   ```
3. Now lets get back to the employee from here: GET *url*/entity/Address/2/employee -> http status 400

In the mentioned example i can flawlessly navigate using all the links for the relationship.

p.s.: I'd like to tag this JPA-RS, but i don't have enough reputation to create a new tag.

Comment: @have created the jpa-rs tag. However I am not familiar with it, and I do not have the required 20k rep to edit teh wiki, so lets be patient :)